# Add-In including Custom Functions still appear in Office 2016/2019 when published using centralized deployment

Tags: office-js

As mentioned here inside the warning block: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements

> If the Office host or platform doesn't support the requirement sets or API members specified in the Requirements element, the add-in won't run in that host or platform, and won't display in My Add-ins.

Based on the above statement I would have assumed, that the add-in that has the requirement set for custom functions will not even appear in Office 2016 and Office 2019 standalone installations. But when we published our add-in using centralized deployment, the add-in appears on these office versions, and everything works in the taskpane, but functions are not loaded. How can we avoid the add-in to even show up in older versions of Office?

Comment: Also adding a manifest file to the seller dashboard including the requirements CustomFunctionsRuntime 1.1 and ExcelAPI 1.9 shows the add in to be supported and validated for Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel 2016 oder higher, Excel Online - this wont work out for this versions. Using ExcelAPI 1.10 instead results in an error because no supported Office products are detected

Answer (score 0):

Please add the requirement set to the add-in's manifest (as below) and central deloy the updated manifest again. The add-in will not appear in lower version of Office.

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set Name="CustomFunctionsRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

The seller dashboard issue is a bug and will be followed up by product team. Thanks.

Comment: I did do it this way, and deployed it centrally. But it still appeared in version of Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 32-bit (Version 1910, Build 12130.20344) and Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 32-bit (Version 1910, Build 12130.20272)

Comment: Would you please share your manifest to us? please send it to ruoyingl@microsoft.com. Thanks.

Comment: @MSFT-Jipyua I have sent you our manifest file on the specified email address.